# Subdownloader is not working anymore

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-player, subtitle, smplayer

It was a great application once, but for me at least it hasn't worked for the last several months.

I can search for subtitles, but when I try to download one, it always displays the message `Unable to download subtitle <subtitle_name>`. I checked the folder the `.gz` file was downloaded to, and it's not a valid archieve. This error/warning message is dumped in the console-

```
(python:21104): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_progress_configure: assertion 'value >= min && value <= max' failed

(python:21104): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_progress_configure: assertion 'value >= min && value <= max' failed

(python:21104): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_progress_configure: assertion 'value >= min && value <= max' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/subdownloader/gui/main.py", line 1126, in onButtonDownload
    osHttpRequests.download('http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/file/%s.gz' %sub.getIdFileOnline(), destinationPath)
  File "/usr/share/subdownloader/modules/OSHttpRequests.py", line 72, in download
    self.unpack_subtitle(gz_path, local_path)
  File "/usr/share/subdownloader/modules/OSHttpRequests.py", line 51, in unpack_subtitle
    fileContent = fileObj.readlines();
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 455, in readline
    c = self.read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 261, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 296, in _read
    self._read_gzip_header()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 190, in _read_gzip_header
    raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'
IOError: Not a gzipped file
```

If this problem is not solvable, could anyone please suggest a alternative that can download subtitles in a bulk, for example for all videos in a folder?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subdownloader/+bug/1375860

Comment: It seems identical to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/subdownloader/+bug/790753

Answer (score 0):

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/subdownloader/+bug/790753 I had a solution:

In the file `/usr/share/subdownloader/gui/main.py`:
Comment line 1143, uncomment the four next lines.

Patch:

```
--- /usr/share/subdownloader/gui/main.py.orig   2016-01-15 20:04:50.880252934 +0100
+++ /usr/share/subdownloader/gui/main.py    2016-01-15 20:05:04.380514034 +0100
@@ -1140,11 +1140,11 @@
                    if not skip_all:
                         log.debug("Downloading subtitle '%s'" % destinationPath)
            #print {sub.getIdFileOnline():destinationPath}
-                        osHttpRequests.download('http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/file/%s.gz' %sub.getIdFileOnline(), destinationPath)
-                        #if self.OSDBServer.DownloadSubtitles({sub.getIdFileOnline():destinationPath}):
-                            #success_downloaded += 1
-                        #else:
-                            #QMessageBox.about(self.window,_("Error"),_("Unable to download subtitle %s") %sub.getFileName())
+                        #osHttpRequests.download('http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/file/%s.gz' %sub.getIdFileOnline(), destinationPath)
+                        if self.OSDBServer.DownloadSubtitles({sub.getIdFileOnline():destinationPath}):
+                            success_downloaded += 1
+                        else:
+                            QMessageBox.about(self.window,_("Error"),_("Unable to download subtitle %s") %sub.getFileName())
                 except Exception, e:
                     traceback.print_exc(e)
                     QMessageBox.about(self.window,_("Error"),_("Unable to download subtitle %s") % sub.getFileName())
```